# Setting Apollo cache / state after mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo 2.0 to manage my graphQL API calls and to handle the global state of my react application.

I am trying to create a login screen where a user enters their username and password, this gets sent to my API to authenticate and upon success, I want to then set the global state of `isLoggedIn` to `true`.

So far, I am able to set the global state with one mutation which utilises the `@client` declaration so it is only concerned with local state. I have another mutation which makes the graphQL API call and validates username / password and then returns success / error responses.

I want to be able to set `isLoggedIn` once the API call mutation has completed or failed.

My client has the following default state and resolvers set like so:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  resolvers: {
    Mutation: {
      updateLoggedInStatus: (_, { isLoggedIn }, { cache }) => {
        const data = {
          loggedInStatus: {
            __typename: 'LoggedInStatus',
            isLoggedIn
          },
        };
        cache.writeData({ data });
        return null;
      },
    },
  },
  defaults: {
    loggedInStatus: {
      __typename: 'LoggedInStatus',
      isLoggedIn: false,
    },
  },
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([stateLink, httpLink])

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
});

export default client
```

Then in my Login component I have the following mutations and queries which I pass as a HOC with the help of compose:

```
const UPDATE_LOGGED_IN_STATUS = gql`
  mutation updateLoggedInStatus($isLoggedIn: Boolean) {
    updateLoggedInStatus(isLoggedIn: $isLoggedIn) @client
  }`

const AUTHENTICATE = gql`
  mutation authenticate($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    auth(username: $username, password: $password) {
      username
      sales_channel
      full_name
      roles
    }
  }`

const GET_AUTH_STATUS = gql`
  query {
    loggedInStatus @client {
      isLoggedIn
    }
  }`

export default compose(
  graphql(GET_AUTH_STATUS, {
    props: ({ data: { loading, error, loggedInStatus } }) => {
      if (loading) {
        return { loading };
      }

      if (error) {
        return { error };
      }

      return {
        loading: false,
        loggedInStatus
      };
    },
  }),
  graphql(UPDATE_LOGGED_IN_STATUS, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      updateLoggedInStatus: isLoggedIn => mutate({ variables: { isLoggedIn } }),
    }),
  }),
  graphql(AUTHENTICATE, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      authenticate: (username, password) => mutate({ variables: { username, password } }),
    }),
  })
)(withRouter(Login));
```

So as you can see I have `this.props.authenticate(username, password)` which is used when the login form is submitted.

Then I have the `this.props.updateLoggedInStatus(Boolean)` which I am able to update the client cache / state.

How do I combine these so that I can call `authenticate()` and if it's successful, set the `loggedInStatus` and if it fails, set a `hasErrored` or `errorMessage` flag of sorts?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have attempted to handle updating the state within the callback of my mutation.

```
// Form submission handler
onSubmit = async ({ username, password }) => {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    this.props.authenticate(username, password)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({loading: false})
        this.props.updateLoggedInStatus(true)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({loading: false, errorMessage: err.message})
        console.log('err', err)
      })
  }
```

Is there a better way of doing it than this? It feels very convoluted having to wait for the call back. I would have thought I could map the response to my cache object via my resolver?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you're currently handling it (calling authenticate and then updateLoggedInStatus) is about as clean and simple as you're going to get with `apollo-link-state`. However, using `apollo-link-state` for this is probably overkill in the first place. It would probably be simpler to derive logged-in status from Apollo's cache instead. For example, you could have a HOC like this:

```
import client from '../wherever/client'

const withLoggedInUser = (Component) => {
  const user = client.readFragment({
  id: 'loggedInUser', 
  fragment: gql`
    fragment loggedInUser on User { # or whatever your type is called
      username
      sales_channel
      full_name
      roles
      # be careful about what fields you list here -- even if the User
      # is in the cache, missing fields will result in an error being thrown
    }
  `
  })
  const isLoggedIn = !!user
  return (props) => <Component {...props} user={user} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}/>
}
```

Notice that I use `loggedInUser` as the key. That means we also have to utilize `dataIdFromObject` when configuring the `InMemoryCache`:

```
import { InMemoryCache, defaultDataIdFromObject } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: object => {
    switch (object.__typename) {
      case 'User': return 'loggedInUser'
      // other types you don't want the default behavior for
      default: return defaultDataIdFromObject(object);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I agree that my current method seems a bit over kill. There is a lot of code and feels like there are a lot of cases I have to check for. I like your example with putting it in a HOC. I'm not that familiar with some of those methods such as `client.readFragment` & `defaultDataIdFromObject` but I like your concept. Will give it a go and update how I get on.

Comment: For your reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/caching.html#readfragment and https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/caching.html#normalization